# Scale number of workers according to number of jobs in gearman

Tags: php, multithreading, gearman

I am using [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) as my job queue manager. Basically i use gearman to manage mail jobs (fire & forget approach). I have a single worker to handle those mail sending jobs. When my application is going to send large amount (>1000) of emails, i can see the queue is growing and it takes some time to process the complete task.

Can i add more workers to  pick jobs from the queue?. Can **Gearman** handle that worker management or should i intentionally add workers by tracking the queue size. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Gearman cannot automatically launch new workers on demand. You can use [GermanManager](https://github.com/myurasov/GearmanManager) with different configs to launch required number of jobs for you when the queue is getting large.

Comment: is there any way by which we can analyze system cpu/capacity and launch more worker accordingly by writing script or code ? any idea or guidance will be really helpful

Comment: also how can we identify that which worker performed particular job ?